# Displaying tableView items by CoreData attribute

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to group section 0 my tableView by the "category" attribute of an item.

Example:

> Drinks: (item.category = header)
>   Dr. Prepper
>   Coke
>   Pepsi
>   Kitchen: (item.category = header)
>   Pots
>   Pans...etc.
>   CrossOff(header)
>   items

I still want section1 to be the item.slcross (or the last section if each group has to be their own section...and it doesn't have to be grouped).

When I change the secondarySortDescriptor key from "slitem" to "slcategory" and use the sectionHeader code below, it returns "nil". I also tried using

`let sectionHeader2 = "\(item.valueForKeyPath("slcategory"))"` but still had the same effect with both "slitem" and "slcategory".

Do I have to use a sort descriptor for each category or is there a way to make it pull the category attribute for the item and group the like categories together?

FRC set up:

```
let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

var selectedItem : List?

func itemFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest{

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
    let primarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slcross", ascending: true)
    let secondarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slitem", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescription, secondarySortDescription]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"slist == true")
    return fetchRequest
}

func getFetchRequetController() ->NSFetchedResultsController{

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: itemFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "slcross", cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}
```

TableViewHeaders:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    let item = List(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

    let sectionHeader = "\(item.slcategory)"
    let sectionHeader1 = "Items in Cart - #\(frc.sections![section].numberOfObjects)"
    if (frc.sections!.count > 0) {
        let sectionInfo = frc.sections![section]
        if (sectionInfo.name == "0") { 
            return sectionHeader2
        } else {
            return sectionHeader1
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an nsfetchedresultscontroller?

Comment: Yes, I am. Do you need more code?

Comment: Hmm maybe where r u setting up the sort descriptors

Comment: I believe in the fetchRequest code. I have the primary as sleeps and secondary as slitem (but tried changing it as above).

Comment: Please can you add the code where you set up the FRC.  To clarify, you want your TV to have a section (with header) for each Category where slcross is 0, plus ONE section for ALL Categories where slcross is 1.  Is that right?

Comment: @WillZimmer when you set up your FetchedResultsController, did you set the sectionNameKeyPath?

Comment: @pdasdf: I believe I added the code you requested. Yes, I am trying to get the all the categories to be grouped together if item.slcross = false (I believe that is what you mean by 0). Then, have one section at the bottom where slcross = true and does not need to be categorized.

Comment: @bolnad isn't that what the sort descriptors do? or does there need to be another line with sectionNameKeyPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but probably the easiest is to add a new method to your `NSManagedObject` subclass.  The method returns a string which will be used as the title for the section; so if `slcross` is false, it returns the value of `slcategory`, and if `slcross` is true it returns "True":

```
func sectionIdentifier() -> String {
    if (self.slcross) {
        return "True"
    } else {
        return "\(self.slcategory)"
    }
}
```

(Note this code goes in your `List` class definition, not your view controller).

In the view controller, use this `sectionIdentifier` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` for your FRC:

```
frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: itemFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: nil)
```

For that to work, it is imperative that the objects are sorted correctly: first by `slcross`, then by `slcategory`:

```
let primarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slcross", ascending: true)
let secondarySortDescription = NSSortDescriptor(key: "slcategory", ascending: true)
```

Finally, amend your `titleForHeaderInSection` to use the section name (which the FRC gets from `sectionIdentifier`), but replacing the "True" with your computed string:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{    
    if (frc.sections!.count > 0) {
        let sectionInfo = frc.sections![section]
        if (sectionInfo.name == "True") { 
            return "Items in Cart - #\(sectionInfo.numberOfObjects)"
        } else {
            return sectionInfo.name
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fixin' to walk out of work to go home. However, judging from your previous answers, this solution will work perfectly. I'll apply this answer when I get back to work this evening and let you know how I do. Thanks for all the knowledge you have passed to me and any future bits as well!

Comment: I had to adapt the code just a little. It was crashing for any other list other than slist. I added  `func sectionIdentifier() -> String {
    if self.slist == true {
        if self.slcross == true {
            return "True"
        } else {
            return "\(self.slcategory!)"
        }
    } else {
    return "false"
    }}` and it seemed to fix the problem. Also, I had to add `"\(self.slcategory!)"` so it wouldn't have "optional ()" in the header. The crashing took me a bit to figure out, but I am starting to figure it out...Other than very minor issues, You have succeeded once again!

Comment: @WillZimmer Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Docs...

> When you initialize the fetch results controller, you provide four parameters: .....
>   ....Optionally, a key path on result objects that returns the section name. The controller uses the key path to split the results into sections (passing nil indicates that the controller should generate a single section).....
>   After creating an instance, you invoke performFetch: to actually execute the fetch.

If you want to sort the sections by category then you need to make the sectionNameKeyPath argument in the `NSFetchedResultsController` init to be your "category" property instead of your "slcross" property.

When I've used this in the past I've also included that same property that I've set as the sectionNameKeyPath in my sort descriptors, but not sure if that is actually needed or not.

Hope I have answered your question?

Comment: Not really, sorry. I have replaced both the key "slcross" and "slitem" (one at a time) and its not working properly. It is not doing what I am looking for it to do. I may still be doing something wrong, but it does not group them by category nor return item.slcategory as the category set. it returns it as nil. Even though the category is saved.